# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash): even though credentials are in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I'm trying to log in as this user on my web app

```
mysql> SELECT*FROM users
    -> ;
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+
| id | username | password_digest | initials |
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+
|  1 | Brett    | brett           | BK       |
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but once I do it throws me this error:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):
```

Clearly I have a username and a password so I'm unsure why I'm not able to log in. I suspect it has something to do with the BCrypt gem and how it accepts passwords but I don't have a clue. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I found a different database on the server and my credentials look like this

```
mysql> SELECT*FROM users;
+----+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| id | username | password_digest                                              | initials |
+----+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 19 | Brett    | $2a$10$isws6DQxsJHzxCOI11miDesJPCNcQN2vfSzmsVpivBx020UshmqHG | BK       |
+----+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

How do I set my password to `brett` and use this crazy combination of numbers and letter to appear in the database? I wish to just use the command line interface.

Here's my User class:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  attr_protected :id 

  has_secure_password 
  has_many :chats, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :cnotes 
  has_one :permission, dependent: :destroy 

  validates :password, confirmation: true 
  validates :username, uniqueness: true 

  def to_param username end 

  def check_permission(permission) 
    self.permission[permission] 
  end 
end
```

Comment: The answer to this is pretty dependent on how you set up your user models.  Are you using devise or some other standardized authentication gem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: The crazy numbers are probably the hash of your password. The makes it impossible for someone to reverse engineer back to your actual password. Applying the same hash algorithm to you password will get you the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `has_secure_password` will enable BCrypt encryption on passwords. In other words, passwords will not be stored in your database in plaintext; instead, they will be encrypted, stored as `password_digest`, and look like that "crazy combination of numbers and letters". This is a ***good*** thing! If your database is ever compromised, the passwords will not be accessible by a third party.

You can find the documentation on `has_secure_password` here: [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)

To set your password to `brett`, you could do the following:

```
user = User.find_by(username: 'Brett')
user.password = 'brett'
user.password_confirmation: 'brett'
user.save
```

In controller during registration this would be something like following

```
def create
  user = User.new user_params
  if user.save
    #do some stuff, redirect to a page for example redirect_to user
  else
     render "new"
  end
end
private 
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation) 
end
```

Then, when logging in, you would use the `authenticate` method to validate that the password entered by the user matches what's stored in the database.

Comment: Where should I put this code to set my password? The User Model?

Comment: @LLBrettK You can run the snippet inside a `rails console`.  Usually something like this will be part of a controller which creates a user (e.g. during registration) or some form of user settings where the user can change her password.